# Page breaking in vtop/hbox

Tags: tables, page-breaking, plain-tex

I'm a new user of Tex and I'm facing a problem related to a very simple situation.

I'm currently working on a TeX (TeXLive, no LaTeX is used) generator. This generator builds TeX files containing generated tables, based on a simple model. Here a table is a set of `\hbox`, with `\vtop` for each column.

```
\hbox{\vtop{column1Content}
      \vtop{column2Content}}
```

The problem arises when the tables have to contain a big content in one "cell", bigger than the size of one page, therefore overflowing a `\vtop`, with printed text going down and nowhere outside the page...

So I was wondering whether it is possible or not to insert page breaks inside a given vtop (column) in order to put the remaining content on the next page, without creating a new `\hbox{\vtop{}}` element (a new line of the table).

I hope I was clear in my description.

Comment: It is a good practice to include a minimum working example with your post, instead of a snippet of code. Could you add one to your question?

Answer (score 7):

A box is an unbreakable unit. So you either have to generate two boxes, or split the box with `\vsplit` or `\unvbox` it to allow the page breaker to split it.

I would say it is a rather surprising choice to generate just plain TeX, a whole host of font and spacing issues would be easier to solve if you generated code for a format that is designed to take care of such issues such as LaTeX or ConTeXt.

Comment: ... But that would take all the fun out of it...